# TFS 2010 build - Reference build path using invokeprocess

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Edit after Mike z reploy

I need to get the string of the path were the Source files are downloaded to the build server from source control. I believe that is called SourcesDirectory.

I've added an invokeprocess activity that calls a powershell script that prints out whatever you pass to the parameter "message". What i need is the name of the variable that holds the binaries directory to pass it to the powershell script (later on i will do more stuff with this variable, of course)

This is how my invokeprocess expression editor looks like:

String.Format(" ""& '{0}' -message '{1}' "" ", "D:\scripts\test.ps1", [placeholder])

All i need is to replace the placeholder with the variable that hold the binaries path (not the drop files) on the build server

Thx!

Comment: What do you mean by "where the binaries are downloaded on the build server"? Typically, there are three important folders: Sources, containing files obtained from source control, TestResults containing test results files, and Binaries containing the build output. Which one of those are you referring to? The default workflow has variables for each one named like SourcesDirectory (and so on).

Comment: Hi Mike - I need "Sources". I'm editing my original question to make it more understandable.

 How would you print that path using the script i provided on my question? Like this?:

String.Format(" ""& '{0}' -message '{1}' "" ", "D:\scripts\test.ps1", SourcesDirectory)

Comment: I knew "SourcesDirectory" was the variable holding the information i needed. I wasnt able to see it because i was placing the InvokeProcess Activity outside the "Run on agent" activity. "SourcesDirectory" scope only works insisde "Run on agent".

Thx for the help!

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to answer my own question still. I will do it in 7 hours

Answer (score 0):

Thx to mike Z's reploy i was able to know that the variable i was looking for was "SourcesDirectory".

To be able to see this variable i had to add the activity inside the "Run on agent" process.

I was not seeing "SourcesDirectory" because i was adding my "Invoke Process" outside "Run on agent".